# SyntaxError: Unexpected token : when running jest test with Aurelia in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, aurelia

Just created a new TypeScript Aurelia project using aurelia-cli . 
Installed bootstrap and included bootstrap css in the app.ts using import.

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../../static/assets/css/app.scss';
import { routes } from './routes';

interface IApp {
  message: string;
}

export class App implements IApp{
  message = 'Hello World!';
}
```

Now when I run the test , I get error unexpected token as below

```
yarn test

# and the output contains

yarn run v1.12.3
$ nps test
nps is executing `test` : nps test.jest
nps is executing `test.jest` : node node_modules/rimraf/bin.js test/coverage-jest && jest
ts-jest[config] (WARN) TypeScript diagnostics (customize using `[jest-config].globals.ts-jest.diagnostics` option):
message TS151001: If you have issues related to imports, you should consider setting `esModuleInterop` to `true` in your TypeScript configuration file (usually `tsconfig.json`). See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2018/01/31/announcing-typescript-2-7/#easier-ecmascript-module-interoperability for more information.
 FAIL  test/unit/app.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To hav`enter code here`e some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :



  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/home/app.ts:163:1)
```

I commented the import bootstrap.css line in app.ts and everything runs fine.

Am I missing some configuration for jest to allow me to use css imports in .ts components?

Here is my jest portion from package.json

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/test"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testRegex": "\\.spec\\.(ts|js)$",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "build",
      "dist",
      "sample"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test/jest-pretest.ts"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,ts}",
      "!**/*.spec.{js,ts}",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/test/**"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/test/coverage-jest",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "lcov",
      "text",
      "html",
      "clover"
    ]

  },
```

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: There is a recent blog about jsdom jest and Aurelia. Maybe it can help you solve the issue you are having? https://discourse.aurelia.io/t/new-blog-post-on-unit-testing-aurelia-with-pug-typescript-and-jest/2034

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error. I resolved my issue by changing the module compilerOption in tsconfig.json from "esnext" to "commonjs". [Why am I getting “Unexpected token import” on one webpack project but not the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711136/why-am-i-getting-unexpected-token-import-on-one-webpack-project-but-not-the-ot)